# Fill a column in Power-BI with date ( the last Thursday date ) dynamically

Tags: excel, powerbi

How to add column in Power-BI transform data and fill it with last Thursday date from the run of the equation ?

I'm going to do some automated file to be run each Sunday or after that

Consider that I'm using Power-BI desktop 2021

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Custom Column with this formula (PowerQuery):

```
Date.AddDays([Date], - Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Thursday))
```

Where `[Date]` is the name of your date column.